# Check for NSUrl redirects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, uiwebview, nsurlconnection

I have a table view that lists job postings for an app pulling from an RSS feed. Unfortunately, quite a few of the job postings that have expired are still left in the feed. The only piece of information that my app could utilize to know that the job is no longer posted (because it uses a link to go to the job posting page) is the fact that when you click on the link and the UIView is pushed, the link that shows up is expired with a message stating, we apologize for the inconvenience, but this position's status has recently changed. On older posts it doesn't load (these are typically posts that start with docs.sitename.doc) and then there's the File not found message without a noted URL redirect link. Is there any direct method worth looking into to possibly filtering these out? At least to where I could note that the positions have expired?

Answer (score 0):

OK, there is a lot to process here.

1. Redirect Detection: If you are using `NSURLConnection`, then look at [Handling Redirects and Other Request Changes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/urlloadingsystem/Articles/RequestChanges.html).
2. Process the RSS: As you load the data from the RSS into your table test the links. If you do this synchronously, then it will cause longer load times. If you do this asynchronously, then you will end up displaying some bad results, which then disappear as the URLs are processed (much like a CoreData update).

As an alternative, see if you can preprocess the RSS. I don't know what server tools you have access to, but it may be worth your while to have a server read the RSS feed and strip out invalid entries. This would create a new RSS feed (on your server) that contains only valid entries.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've got 0 access to the RSS server side. Trust me, I'd use that to my advantage if I did. The URL link itself is a link pulled from the feed (say a feed with a job posting and then a link to apply). The link itself is just an element for the item. Although, there may be a way to start parsing in the link and use something in there as verification. I was wondering/hoping there would be something where I could say... try to go to this link... does it exist... if not .. do this. I'm guessing I'd handle this through another NSURLConnection through the item's link